# Can I commit directly to a remote Git repository?

Tags: git

I'm setting up Git on a network drive. Due to the sensitivity of the contents, the code cannot be pushed to a cloud-hosted Git solution like GitHub, etc. Personally, I'll be committing to a local (cloned) repository and then pushing to the network drive, but others in the office may make changes directly to the network drive. Can these changes be committed directly to the remote? What happens if the changes aren't committed at all? How are they handled? Alternatively, would it be better to make the network repository "local," and then just refrain from adding a remote at all?

Comment: You can commit to a git repo on a network drive, but it's a bad idea. The best bet is to use a self-hosted git repo (simple git via ssh on a Linux server or something like gittea).

Comment: I don't think I can self-host git unfortunately. But what happens when a change is made directly to a folder set as a git remote? Like if I just went in and changed something without making git aware of it whatsoever.

Comment: Hold up, "without committing"? How are you going to make changes without committing? Maybe you meant "without pushing" or something along those lines.

Comment: No I meant without committing. I'm going to try and get everyone on the same page as far as the "new" system goes, but *if* someone makes a change directly to the network drive, without realizing they have to commit changes, etc, I want to make sure I can repair it (or that it doesn't cause any damage in the first place).

Comment: @MattVotes Ohhhh, ok. So I take it your team doesn't use Git already? Cause this seems like a weird setup. Normally remotes are bare repos, so the content isn't directly editable.

Comment: Correct, I think it's a fairly new concept for most of the editors here. I'm starting to read the documentation on bare repos, looks like that'll do the trick. Thanks :)

Comment: The safest way to avoid people accidentally making changes without committing is to make the remote git repository (the one on the network drive) a bare repository without a commit. This way there's no files to accidentally change. The only way to reasonably use that is to clone it somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Git is meant to be a distributed VCS. While it's generally used with a central source of truth (think Github, Gitlab etc.), there's nothing stopping from using it fully distributed, with many people having their own clones and everyone pushing and pulling to/from each other. In this case, every person represents a remote for your local.

If you make a change on network drive and never commit it, then it cannot be pulled to other clones. You have to use rsync or something, but that beats a lot of git's purpose.

Also, any uncommitted changes are always unsafe. i.e. they can get deleted, reverted very easily, and you'll not be able to recover them.

Moreover, since changes aren't getting committed, you lose out on change history, diffs and a lot of features that make version control great. In other words, if you're not committing, you're not really using version control at all.

*Suggestion: Use network drive as a remote (like Github). Everyone clones that to their own local, commit changes and push to this remote network drive. Additionally, back up this network drive to protect against data loss.*

*If people absolutely have to write directly to network drive, at least make sure they're committing changes. The suggestion for backups still stands.*

Comment: Gotcha. If a change is made to the network drive without committing, is that fixable? How would I do that?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by fixable, but if there are already changes on network drive, I’d start by committing those. Going forward, changes should be committed as they’re made.